# Sqoop export failing while export parquet files from S3 to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqoop, amazon-emr, parquet

I am trying to export a parquet file form S3 to SQL Server using Sqoop and I get this error:

> 19/07/09 16:12:57 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI pattern: dataset:s3://mybucket/data-lake/serving-zone/part-00002-b5a1da42.snappy.parquet
>   Check that JARs for s3 datasets are on the classpath
>   org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI pattern: dataset:s3://mybucket/data-lake/serving-zone/part-00002-b5a1da42.snappy.parquet
>   Check that JARs for s3 datasets are on the classpath
>           at org.kitesdk.data.spi.Registration.lookupDatasetUri(Registration.java:128)
>           at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.load(Datasets.java:103)
>           at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.load(Datasets.java:140)
>           at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyInputFormat$ConfigBuilder.readFrom(DatasetKeyInputFormat.java:92)
>           at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyInputFormat$ConfigBuilder.readFrom(DatasetKeyInputFormat.java:139)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JdbcExportJob.configureInputFormat(JdbcExportJob.java:83)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:434)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.exportTable(SQLServerManager.java:192)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Dataset is present on the above location and no issue with path URI. I have tried to export a CSV file from same path and it worked.

Below is my Sqoop Export Command:

```
sqoop export --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
             --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager 
             --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=salesdb"  
             --table DimEmployee_test --num-mappers 128 
             --export-dir s3://mybucket/data-lake/serving-zone/part-00002-b5a1da42.snappy.parquet
             --username db-user --password mypassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Your --connect URI seems awkward try using this format instead:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>
```